# C# IE11 Automation - Setting Doc Form Elements Given Only Window Handle

Tags: c#, automation, internet-explorer-11

I have connected to an open IE11 window with the following C# code.  However I have no idea how to access it's document elements using getElementID as I need to read and set these.

```
//Import the FindWindow API to find our window
[DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
private static extern int FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);

//Import the SetForeground API to activate it
[DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

......

// Find the IE window
int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "ACME Form Input - Internet Explorer");

if (hWnd > 0) // The IE window was found.
{
    // Bring the IE window to the front.
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
```

With this code above how do I access the IE document to get and set it's form elements?  Please help!

Andy

Comment: just commenting since I'm not really answering your question, but selenium is a good (probably better) way of automating web browsers.

Comment: One of the things that I'm doing is watching a folder for new text files, opening a text file, looping through each line and passing data to a web page for processing.  Can Selenium do this as well?

Comment: I went ahead and posted it as an answer because I feel it will accomplish your goals

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment, I'd recommend using something like the filesystemwatcher class to monitor your folder, the standard System.IO stuff for the text file manipulation, then selenium for the website automation. Basically, selenium can act as chrome, firefox, etc (or headless) and locate the html elements on the page and send text, click buttons, etc.

Comment: I've got Selenium up and running using Chrome.  However there doesn't seem to be a way to link to an open instance of Chrome.  You have to start a new browser instance every single time?

Comment: Correct. If you can use a profile to load the driver with certain settings but cookies and stuff will be cleared out each time. Also you'll want to make sure you're disposing of the driver properly so you don't have a bunch of processes left running.

Answer (score 0):

To access the document element in the manner you are wanting to you will need to cast or assign the ie.document to a mshtml document. You will need to add ref to mshtml and I have an example below showing the assignment.

```
        SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Search\n\n\n");

        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
        {
            if (ie.LocationURL.Contains("aavtrain"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ie.LocationURL);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("FOUND!\n");

                mshtml.HTMLDocument document = ie.Document;
                mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection elCol = document.getElementsByName("user_name");
                mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection elCol2 = document.getElementsByName("password");
                mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection elCol3 = document.getElementsByName("Submit");

                Console.WriteLine("AutofillPassword");


                foreach (mshtml.IHTMLInputElement i in elCol)
                {
                    i.defaultValue = "John";
                }

                foreach (mshtml.IHTMLInputElement i in elCol2)
                {
                    i.defaultValue = "Password";
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Will Click Button in 2 seconds");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                foreach (mshtml.HTMLInputButtonElement i in elCol3)
                {

                    i.click();
                }


            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
```